# Partial image is being uploaded to parse.com using restapi

Tags: python, django, parse-platform

when i tried to upload image to parse.com using restapi by the following python script, only partial image is being uploaded..

i got following json response

{"url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/a224a144-55ca-4815-917e-b911d44ac121/tfss-08a78f3e-d95c-48be-b64f-2c564d310e38-pdr11.jpg", "name": "tfss-08a78f3e-d95c-48be-b64f-2c564d310e38-pdr11.jpg"}

when i tried to open the url in response only partial image of 2kb is uploaded

the actual size of image is 553kb..

view.py

```
def index(request):
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()
    querySetList = Post.objects.all()
    imageToUpload = open("D:\\Beautiful-Android-cell-phone-wallpapers-480x854-06.jpg","rb")
    #print imageToUpload.name

    connection.request('POST', '/1/files/pdr11.jpg', open(str(imageToUpload.name), 'r+').read(), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "NMVvDdhhWfvs6tBcxTSta7RZWVn47TqpJsrXkboh",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "G5flmDwYy44tdVPoR3q5eBbjaIREVew5hKWqMr7S",
       "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
     })
    result1 = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result1),content_type='application/json')
```